# Why did they change how the characters looked in the Lego Ninjago Movie?

Tags: character, set-design, adaptation, the-lego-ninjago-movie

From watching *The Lego Ninjago Movie*, I am very confused. Yes, while there are so many differences and changes I question and wonder about, there is one major one that I do not understand the most: Why did they change the designs of the characters? Of course, I knew the movie would have changes, but why did they make the ninjas designs completely different? So far, I could never really find a valid reason on why.

Comment: To sell a new set of toys?